# Has mongoid replacement for rails save(touch: false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Ruby on Rails active_record has option {touch: false}, when record is saved to database, since version 5. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/09/rails-5-allows-updating-without-updating-timestamps.html

I can not find if this (or similar) option is implemented in mongoid too. {touch: false} doesn't seem to work.

by
TheR

Answer (score 1):

#### Nope :(

I don't think it does Pal!

How I checked:

1. Download source and search with `grep`.

`git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git`

The persistable instance methods all use an options Hash and I couldn't see any mention of the `touch` option.

2. Searched through the documentation over at https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/7.1/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/index.html

#### A potential workaround

This is pseudo code I've typed quickly as I don't know Mongoid's DSL from memory, it's based on ActiveRecord.

```
object = Object.find(1)
update = object.updated_at

object.update(update_the_object: :attributes_you_want_to)
# Use a method that doesn't update timestamps automatically to, well, update the timestamps.
object.update_column(updated_at: update)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

Mongoid has timeless method which does just what I wanted.

```rb
my_document.timeless.save
```

I also made a request to mongoid team and it looks like the above functionality will be implemented around mongoid v8.

by
TheR